# Spring Data JPA - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using CURDRepository, when calling save menthod below exception got:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching
> TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' -
> neither qualifier match nor bean name match!

whereas, when calling other function from repo like findALL  and findByID they are working fine, below is code for config, repo and calling fucntion.

// config

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "emfRequest")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("dsRequest") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.Digit4G.domain").build();
}


@Primary
@Bean(name = "tmRequest")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(               
        @Qualifier("emfRequest") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

// Repository

```
@Repository
public interface Digit4GRepo<P> extends CrudRepository<Digit4GRequest, Long> {
       public List<Digit4GRequest> findBySUBNOAndIMEI(String subno, String IMEI);
       public Digit4GRequest save(Digit4GRequest request);   
}
```

// calling function

```
Digit4GRequest obj =  new Digit4GRequest();

    obj.setSUBNO(subno);
    obj.setIMEI(IMEI);
    obj.setIMSI(IMSI);
    obj.setPACKAGENAME(packageName);
    digit4GRepo.save(obj);
```

Comment: if you are using spring-boot make sure you are using @EnableTransactionManagement and your repository should be inside your base package.

Comment: You set explicitly a different bean name for your transactionManager, so the convention does not work. `@Bean(name = "tmRequest")` . Try to remove `name = "tmRequest"`

Comment: @mrkernelpanic thanks this worked. but i am still confuse why findById was working before if that was the issue.

Comment: `findById` does not run in a transaction, because it is only read-only operation, whereas `save` runs inside a transaction, because it changes data.